# How can I find the implement .cc file in Omnet++ INET's examples

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I'm a fresh newer studying INET in Omnet now. I try to find out how the INET's examples like tutorial wireless networks work, but there are only ned and ini file in that directory without cc file. So I am very confused how this network works. Anyone can tell me how can i find it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `C++` files in `INET` examples because the whole behaviour of every module, protocol, channel, packet etc. used by `INET` has already been defined in `C++` files in `src` directory. The compiled and ready to use code is present in file `src\libINET.dll` (or `src/libINET.so` for Linux). 
To get to know *how* a protocol was modelled look inside a module and look for simple modules. (In `OMNeT++` the behaviour is defined only for simple modules.)
For example:

1. In the `examples\wireless\lan80211` there is `Lan80211.ned`. Open it in source (text) format. This network uses (between other things) `WirelessHost`.
2. Go to declaration of `WirelessHost` (Hint: select this word and press F3 or click this word holding Ctrl). One can see that `WirelessHost` inherits from `StandardHost` and from `NodeBase`. Moreover: `numRadios=1` and `mgmtType = "Ieee80211MgmtSTASimplified"`.
3. In `NodeBase.ned` one can see that it uses `Ieee80211Nic` wlan module by default. The module `Ieee80211Nic` is defined in `src\inet\linklayer\ieee80211\Ieee80211Nic.ned`.
4. Looking inside `Ieee80211Nic` one can see that it uses `Ieee80211Mac` (between other things). This is a simple module defined in `\src\inet\linklayer\ieee80211\mac\Ieee80211Mac.ned`. And its behaviour is defined in `\src\inet\linklayer\ieee80211\mac\Ieee80211Mac.cc`.

This way one can discover a simple module and its `C++` code of every compound module. However, take into account that to understand how the compound module works the connections between simple modules should be considered too.

Comment: Thanks, so all the simple modules like 80211 mac layer has been defined in the INET module. If I want to add a customize layer between mac layer and network layer to handle network coding. How can I combine the customize module and INET module.

Comment: The simplest way to do it is to create a new `OMNeT++` project and set `INET` as referenced project. Moreover, in you new project you should define own NED file for your host. Host will inherit from `StandardHost`. I suggest adding a new question for this issue and I will provide you a sample code for solution.

Comment: Thank you Jerzy, I have added a new question about this already.

Comment: Hi Jerzy, could you provide a simple code for solution to my new question which name is How can I combine my customize module with Omnet++INET's simple module. Thank you very much.